# Grant view definition in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

How to grant view definition for all objects on a database in SQL Server 2000

Comment: i meant ...how to grant permission for a specific user to view all the objects in a particular database.

Comment: I think that's a new permission in SQL Server 2005 - in 2000, all users are able to see all object definitions, afaik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user can see all objects in SQL Server 2000: there is no metadata visibility.

They may not have EXECUTE or SELECT permissions though.

Unfortunately, there are no fine-grained permissions in SQL Server 2000 so you'll have to grant ddl_admin, db_owner or query syscomments.